# Picture grid without borders in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a picture grid in Bootstrap without borders like this http://bit.ly/1TCfdl9, but what I've done so far is all in mess currently. Of course I could just paste one big picture, but every one of these photos needs to be a link, and have a hover effect that will point to some information.

Here's the code so far:

```
    <section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="" class="img-responsive" id="prvaslika" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                60%
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Al Jazeera Balkans
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/images/2ASA%20Group.png" class="prvaslika img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/images/3dm.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/images/4Violeta.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/images/5Sberbank.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/images/6Microsoft.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the custom CSS:

```
.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  background:  rgba(123, 38, 169, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category,
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}

.text-faded {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.drugaslika {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

#prvaslika {
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url("/img/images/1Aljazeera.png");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 80%;
    margin-right:-100px;
}
```

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to fix?

Comment: You might want to look at this SO article: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve